# Adding to a url to tick a checkbox

Tags: javascript, url, get

I have a URL www.example.com/index.html

It has an element with an id of DARK_MODE.
It is a checkbox.

I want to add to the URL so that when it loads it automatically gets ticked.

I tried www.example.com/index.html?DARK_MODE=checked

This is not my website that i'm loading.

Am i doing this right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I propose. In order to check the checkbox, use, `?DARK_MODE=checked`.

```js
var $_GET = {};
if(document.location.toString().indexOf('?') !== -1) {
    var query = document.location
        .toString()
        .replace(/^.*?\?/, '')
        .replace(/#.*$/, '')
        .split('&');
    for(var i=0, l=query.length; i<l; i++) {
        var aux = decodeURIComponent(query[i]).split('=');
        $_GET[aux[0]] = aux[1];
    }
}

if($_GET['DARK_MODE'] === 'checked') document.getElementById('DARK_MODE').checked = true;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="DARK_MODE" />
```

Comment: Does it matter that it is not my website? I'm still working my way through your example.